# How does the die rolling work in Betrayal at House on the Hill?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

There are a lot of parts into the game where i just dont know what to do with the die. For example, when I have to roll a 3+ to cross a bridge, how many dice is it when it's not a might or speed or sanity or knowledge roll?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have multiple unrelated questions, please ask each separately rather than all in one. I've answered your first question here; you can edit out the others and make other questions. Also, have you read the rulebook? Most of the questions you've asked here are pretty basic and should be easily answerable by reading the rules (it's not a long rulebook).

Comment: I went ahead and kept only the first of the questions, since it's the one that was in the title and the body, so it seemed important. Please do repost the others, though!

Comment: To briefly answer the questions that got edited out:
1: The turn doesn't end but your movement goes to 0. Normally this means you have nothing else to do so you end your turn, but you can still use items and interact with things in the room (e.g. try to open the vault).
2: You draw a card for a room tile when you enter that room only as you reveal it. You might draw several cards if events cause you to reveal and move into new rooms.
3: If you have to draw for a particular floor you discard tiles until you get a valid floor. When you run out, shuffle the pile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of dice you roll is equal to your stat for the roll you need. So if it tells you to make a might roll, and your might is 3, then you roll 3 dice.

Comment: It was a little unclear originally (I edited a bit), but I think the OP thought that there were some places where it didn't actually tell you a stat. I don't think that's the case, though; for example the bridge on the tower says "a might roll of 3+", the chasm says "a speed roll of 3+", and so on. (I don't own the game, going off images online, sorry if I messed something up.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few separate rolls that aren't based on a trait. Usually, if there's no trait to check it'll tell you how many dice to use. This includes events such as the granny on the telephone and rooms such as the mystic elevator (both 2 dice, from memory).

One common type of roll that doesn't use a trait is the **haunt roll**, which you roll after each omen card is drawn. As detailed in the general rules, a haunt roll is always 6 dice, and succeeds (doesn't trigger the haunt) if the result is at least the number of omen cards drawn so far. Since you can roll up to 12 on 6 dice, there are 13 omen cards (and omen room tiles) to guarantee that a haunt will always happen eventually.